LED Drive using FET: Which scenario will work?
Which scenario will work in the below image? If not, can you suggest a fet which will work for all 3 scenarios?


They'll all probably light up but brightness is going to be hard to predict since the threshold voltage could be above or below those voltages.

Nazim - Hi, Your related question yesterday showed a schematic with a BJT. Now you're asking about a FET, even though you tagged both questions as BJT and FET. What's going on? FYI, if you ask follow-on questions, it's good to link to previous related questions, explain why you're asking another one, what has changed or is different to the previous one etc. || Basically, just add some narrative to explain what's going on. Otherwise people can get annoyed if they discover undisclosed previous related questions, that might alter their answers to later questions. TY

@Nazim, your question is unclear to me. Are you looking for the LED to be illuminated for all 3 Gate voltages? What does 24E represent? You should include your own working in your question, make it clear what part of the problem you do not understand.

Take a look at the electrical characteristics listed in the Diodes Inc. BSS138 datasheet, page 2:

Parameter \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ here tells you what potential difference between gate and source is necessary to pass 250μA of current through whatever is connected at the drain, an LED in your case.
You'll require more than 250μA, though, so you'll find you require slightly more than these quoted figures.
If you are lucky, then your own device will have \$V_{GS(TH)}=0.5V\$. In that case you might find that every single one of the scenarios you proposed will work well, and the LED will light up just fine.
If you are unlucky, then your \$V_{GS(TH)}=1.5V\$, and only the last of your scenarios will work. Even then it's borderline.
You certainly should not rely on luck, so my advice is don't use the BSS138 unless you are sure that gate potential will significantly exceed 2.0V.
We are discouraged from recommending products here, so I won't find a suitable part for you. However, I can recommend that you use the filter tools of Digikey and Mouser to find a transistor with \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ low enough for your application. Here's a link to the filter page for MOSFETs at Mouser.


can you suggest a fet which will work for all 3 scenarios?

Well, not a FET.
A NPN BJT with a resistor in series with the base.

I can't use bjt. Ineed a circuit where we can only sink less than 90nA for driving led?

If I drive base it will sink more than uA

"I need a circuit where we can only sink less than 90 nA" -- Then you should say so in the body of your question. Please edit your question and add that requirement.
